# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/core/Tracer$Builder - Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to execute an WordCount example with Scala Spark but I am having the following problem:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/core/Tracer$Builder
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsTracer.get(FsTracer.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:226)
    at es.santander.prueba.pruebas.WordCount.count(WordCount.scala:123)
    at es.santander.prueba.pruebas.WordCount.main(WordCount.scala:50)
    at es.santander.prueba.pruebas.Main$.main(WordCount.scala:27)
    at es.santander.prueba.pruebas.Main.main(WordCount.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.core.Tracer$Builder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 11 more
```

I have been searching to fix this problem and I add to my pom.xml the following jars:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.htrace/htrace-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.htrace</groupId>
    <artifactId>htrace-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.htrace/htrace-hbase -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.htrace</groupId>
    <artifactId>htrace-hbase</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0-incubating</version>
</dependency>
```

But the problem persist, Am I doing wrong something or do I need something more?

**EDIT**: This is where I am having the error:

```
    FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration).delete(new Path(outputFile), true)
```

Comment: you need to create the ubejar using maven assembly plugin

Comment: @AlexOtt thanks for your response! How can I do this?

Comment: https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html for example

Comment: @CloudSparkie, follow this link https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html and also ensure that you add an extra xml tag for every dependency <scope>provided</scope>

Comment: @AlexOtt is not there an example for this problem? I've never created an uber jar :|

Comment: Examples of what? Yes, there are plenty of examples creating uber/fat jars. By the way, you should not be using different versions of htrace, especially not an incubating one with a stable one... Besides that, you don't need htrace or hbase to run wordcount. You **do need** `spark-core` and maybe `spark-sql`

Comment: @OneCricketeer It was I thought but I am having the problem that I said in the line of code that I put in the post (edited)

Comment: just google search for "Spark maven uber jar" or "Spark maven fat jar", you will find a lot of blogs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I have been reading about create an uber jar, but my doubt now is, uber jar about what HTrace Core? Spark Core?